# How to create and store json array of objects in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to test Newtonsoft deserialize of JSON data. I wanted to create an array of json objects and deserialize them.

For example

My code:

```
public class TestJson
{
    public string thing1
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string thing2
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}

var json = ??????
```

What I tried

```
var json = [{thing1:"f",thing2="x"},{thing1:"c",thing2="bx"}];

//The above line is givig compiler error in C#

List <TestJson> exam = new List<TestJson>();
exam = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TestJson>>(json);
```

My objective isto create json aray pf objects and then deserialize them to class. I am using Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize.

Comment: odds are that you got a syntax error.  What did the syntax error message say?

Comment: @Sam ,Is i possible to deserialize the above json data?

Comment: well, I've never come across the `Is i possible to deserialize the above json data?` syntax error before, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: ; expected is the error

Comment: That usually means that you forgot to put a `;` at the end of the previous line.  currently, I don't see any code that should cause that error though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here appears to be the json string:

```
var json = [{thing1:"f",thing2="x"},{thing1:"c",thing2="bx"}];
```

Firstly, the DeserializeObject method expects a string as a parameter.
Secondly, JSON requires key names to be surrounded by quotes.
Thirdly, JSON syntax for key/value pairs is key:value not key=value

Therefore the correct syntax would be:

```
var json = "[{ \"thing1\": \"f\",\"thing2\" : \"x\"},{ \"thing1\": \"c\",\"thing2\" : \"bx\"}]";
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try to use this syntax:

```
string json = @"[{'thing1':'a1', 'thing2':'a2'}, {'thing1':'b1', 'thing2':'b2'}, {'thing1':'c1', 'thing2':'c2'}]";
```

I think it's easy to write this way, and for set value you should use ':', not '=' like at (thing2="x")

i hope help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newtonsoft JSON for both serializing and deserializing, after initializing the object. A simple example is:

```
TestJson[] testArr = new TestJson[] { new TestJson() { thing1 = "a1", thing2 = "a2" },
                                      new TestJson() { thing1 = "b1", thing2 = "b2" }
                                    };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testArr);
//Serialized string is: [{"thing1":"a1","thing2":"a2"},{"thing1":"b1","thing2":"b2"}]
TestJson[] newObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestJson[]>(json);
```